# Dynamic variable names using ajax json response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting ajax json response through that response i want to generate variables like..

```
var x=data.array1[0].qty_value;

var y=dataa.array2[0].x;
```

here x value not accepting how can write...

```
if(data.array1[0].rate_preload != ''){
    var xyz=data.array1[0].rate_preload;
    var rate_val=data.array2[0].this['xyz'];
    $('#rate1').val(rate_val);
}
```

Comment: please give your JSON data format

Comment: array1: [{id: "16", transaction_id: "7", screen_name: " Purchase Quotation ", b_heading: "", b_alias: "",…}]
0: {id: "16", transaction_id: "7", screen_name: " Purchase Quotation ", b_heading: "", b_alias: "",…}
qty_preload: "buying_rate"
rate_preload: "buying_rate1"
screen_name: " Purchase Quotation "
transaction_id: "7"
updated_at: "2019-09-30 11:49:59"
array2: [,…]
0: {id: "9", name: "hp", alias: "", Code: "", Type: "Finished Good", level: "", Valuation: "1", bin: "",…}

buying_rate1: "1500"
buying_rate2: ""
buying_rate3: ""
buying_rate4: ""
buying_rate5: ""
buying_rate6: ""

Comment: show full response json.

Answer (score 0):

replace it with with the 3rd line

```
var rate_val=data.array2[0][xyz];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it's giving error like..Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['

Comment: This is not the way to access the object. It should be without period.